# I bought an option it has a volume of 3 it expires two weeks from the purchase date it jumped 650% and drops then rises even higher

Tags: options, trading

I bought 5 options contracts. It goes from being worth $125 then shoots up to over $1,000 then decreases in value when I try to sell. I tried to sell three times while it had a 552% increase, but it dropped to a 10% increase. I left it alone and an hour later it rose back up higher to a 652% increase.

My option that rose from 10% in 30 minutes with low volume:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I bought 5 contracts and It goes from being worth $125 then shoots up to over $1,000 then decreases in value when I try to sell i tried to sell 3 times while it had al 552% increase and it dropped it to a 10% increase i left it alone and an hour later it rose back up higher to a 652% increase help!

Comment: Please don't use comments to add details... please [edit] them into the question.

Comment: Recommendation: You shouldn't trade options if you don't understand the basics. Would you let a two-year old drive your car?

Comment: I suspect that you might be  using a broker like Robinhood whose quote is the average of the bid and ask.  When the spread widens or narrows, it appears that the option's value is jumping or dropping a large percent.  If that 's the case, you need to look at the actual bid and ask during real time to see where the market actually is.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. What is the question you’d like to ask?

Comment: Is this during regular trading hours or after hours?

Comment: What is the name of the trading platform and the underlying stock?

Answer (score 1):

If the volume of a financial instrument is very low, the market is something like a swap meet. Tell the other market participants what you are willing to sell for, using a limit sell order. The other market participants can take it or leave it. You can revise your order as you like, as well.